# Where is my log output going?

Tags: r, ruby, ubuntu, logging, stdout

I'm executing an R-script from within ruby using the following command:

```
country = "de"
system("cd ~/myrep/production && Rscript --vanilla main.r --country #{country} --environment production &> /home/myuser/dir/shared/log/log_#{country}.log &")
```

The log file is created, however I find no output in the file, where as if I execute the command straight in the OS like so:

```
cd ~/myrep/production && Rscript --vanilla main.r --country de --environment production
```

Then I see output I see lot's of output in the terminal

**update**

As suggested in the comments I tried changing the redirect. It didn't work. When doing a `ps aux` in the terminal, it looks like the actual command being executed is actually:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R --slave --no-restore --vanilla --file=main.r --args --country de --environment production
```

So without the output redirection to file...?

Comment: Does the same situation happen also with some other program than Rscript, or is it only Rscript? I am thinking whether `r` tag is accurate in this question...

Comment: what if you use `> file 2>&1` instead of `&> file`?

Comment: So in this case it would be: `cd ~/myrep/production && Rscript --vanilla main.r --country #{country} --environment production > /home/myuser/dir/shared/log/log_#{country}.log 2>&1 &` or? is that right @eddi?

Comment: yep - does that also fail?

Comment: Still doesn't work (see update)